# Multiple Sectional divisions in a Memoir header

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, memoir

How would you have a page heading so that on the Left hand page you might have the Book the Part and the Chapter and on the right hand page have a Section any existing subsection.

From reading the Memoir manual and http://tug.org/pracjourn/2008-2/madsen/madsen.pdf it appears you can only put one item into the header at a time via the \rightmark \leftmark.

so just to be clear I would like something like:

> Page Number • Part Title • Chapter Title   |   Section Title • Subsection Title • Page Number

where the vertical bar is the page gutter

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: No: you use the `\...mark` commands in your `\make...head` commands. The former only contain one 'thing', but you can put all sorts of arbitrary stuff in the latter.

Comment: I realize this, I was just trying to show the result I was after... so I edited the question in an attempt to make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it appears you can only put one item into the header at a time via the
>   \rightmark \leftmark.

That is true, but not the whole truth. You can work round it by concatenating several data items into a mark, and then selecting the appropriate item when you print the header.

Since parts and chapters are unlikely to be less than 2 pages long, you can remember the titles in normal macro definitions, or you could pack them into `\leftmark` in the same way this packs the section and subsection titles into `\rightmark`

This is the bare bones of a solution to show the basic idea. Adding the functionality cleanly to the standard `\part`, `\chapter`, etc, commands is an independent sub-problem.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xstring}

\makeatletter

% Define some commands so we can renew them later
\newcommand{\savepart}{}
\newcommand{\savechapter}{}
\newcommand{\savesection}{}

% This is intentionally over-simple code, but packaging the additions cleanly into
% \part, \section, etc doesn't add value to explainng what to do.

% Assuming that chapters will cover at least two pages, we can just save the
% part and chapter titles withouut using marks.

\newcommand{\mypart}[1]{\renewcommand{\savepart}{#1}\part{#1}}
\newcommand{\mychapter}[1]{\renewcommand{\savechapter}{#1}\chapter{#1}}

% We also need to save the section title, so we can use it when we start
% each subsection
\newcommand{\mysection}[1]{\renewcommand{\savesection}{#1}\section{#1}}

% In the subsection, pack the two titles into the mark, with a unique separator @@@
% Note: you probably want to add a \markright commmand to \mysection as well, 
% in case you have a section with no subsections.

\newcommand{\mysubsection}[1]
  {\subsection{#1}\markright{\savesection @@@#1}}

% Finally, define the headings, and extract the two substrings from the \rightmark

\makeevenhead{headings}%
  {\thepage}{\savepart}{\savechapter}
\makeoddhead{headings}%
  {\StrBefore{\rightmark}{@@@}}{\StrBehind{\rightmark}{@@@}}{\thepage}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\mypart{Part A}
\mychapter{Chapter One}
\newpage
\mysection{Sec 11}
\mysubsection{SubSec aaa}
\newpage
\mysubsection{SubSec bbb}
\newpage
\mysubsection{SubSec ccc}
\newpage
\mypart{Part B}
\mychapter{Chapter Two}
\newpage
\mysection{Sec 22}
\mysubsection{SubSec ddd}
\newpage
\mysubsection{SubSec eee}
\newpage
\mysubsection{SubSec fff}

\end{document}
```